# Google Sitelinks Searchbox - error when input value specified

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata, html-input, google-rich-snippets

I'm implementing [Google's Sitelinks searchbox](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/sitelinks-searchbox) on my website, and using their [Structured Data Testing tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) to validate.

I'm getting the error below, after some elimination, it's because I'm using a default input value `value="Search the site"`, if I remove this property/value or set it to null `value=""`, the the page validates ok!

Is there a workaround for this as my searchbox is a little bare without the default value?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I should add i've got a jquery workaround which adds the value dynamically but i hoped to do this without a client-side language and with pure html 

$("#kword").val("Search the site");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google’s SDTT seems to give an error for every space-separated string in `value`, starting from the second one. So `value="a"` gives no error, `value="a b"` gives one error, `value="a b c"` gives two errors etc.

But your issue can be solved on the HTML level:

As it doesn’t seem to make sense to search for "Search the site", the [`value` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-input-value) shouldn’t be used for it. It should only be used for default values.

Use the [`placeholder` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-input-placeholder) instead:

> The `placeholder` attribute represents a *short* hint (a word or short phrase) intended to aid the user with data entry when the control has no value.

So your `input` element could be:

```
<input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search the site" id="keyword" title="Enter search keywords" itemprop="query-input" required />
```

Comment: thanks for that, I didn't realise there was a placeholder attribute!  This will do just fine :)